# JsonToTree example from QooXdoo 2.1 demo not working in playground

Tags: json, qooxdoo

I am trying to get the JsonToTree example working, however it does not work in the playground: `http://tinyurl.com/b92lkn9` and it does not work when done locally on my system. 
Interestingly, the example works fine inside the demo browser
`http://demo.qooxdoo.org/2.1/demobrowser/index.html#data~JsonToTree.html`

If i bring this part out of the event listener, 
`tree.getRoot().setOpen(true);`
it gives me an error saying the tree.getRoot() is null.

Some other questions regarding this have been solved by pointing that the Json file did not have a root node. However I am using the same JSON as given in demo browser example.
tree.json looks like this:
http://demo.qooxdoo.org/2.1/demobrowser/resource/demobrowser/demo/data/tree.json

Any pointers for this issue. I am stuck here.

Thanks in advance.
Vishal

Comment: I think i found what the issue is, the URL should be something that is served by the server, a Json file cannot be picked up just like that by the browser...right. So I need to create an XHR request that gets this JSON file and then parse it to create a model. Then bind the model to the controller.

Comment: I have an update. I reverted to using the same code as in the example, and now everything is working on my local machine. I have put the tree.json file in the same folder as my icons. The store now finds the file and I see the tree in my left container of the split pane I am using. Not sure what went wrong in the first try. The qx.data.store.json() also does all the URL fetching etc.

Answer (score 0):

The sample can not work in the playground as the data json file is missing and can not be loaded when copying the code over. But as you already mentioned in your comment, if you put the json file on your server, it should work and you should not have any cross origin policy issues anymore.